# Core data weird NSValidationError during save

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I have a an NSOperationQueue that run multiple concurrent NSOperations. These operations are creating NSManagedObjects, settings relationships and attributes on them and saving them in the persistent store. The problem occurs during saves, I get this kind of errors :

> "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "The operation couldn't be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)" UserInfo=0x1787c7a0
>
> {NSValidationErrorObject= (entity:
>   SynchronizationStep; id: 0x178749a0
>   
>   ; data:  {
>
> dummyId = nil;
>
> code = 2040;
>
> creationDateTime = "2014-04-24 09:45:26 +0000";
>
> .... other properties .... }),
>
> NSValidationErrorKey=dummyId, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.)}"

So I completely understand that the "dummyId" is not "optional" in the data model, so the object cannot be saved with a "nil" value for this attribute. But this value value cannot be nil, it is not used at all anywhere (I keep it for historical reasons..), and the only place where it is used is in an awakeFromInsert method, where I set it a default value (this is a transformable attribute, the transformer works well on other attributes, so it cannot be that) :

```
- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    // add a default value for the "dummyId" attribute if it is not already set.

    if ([[[self entity] attributesByName] objectForKey: @"dummyId"] && ![self primitiveValueForKey: @"dummyId"])
        [self setPrimitiveValue: [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString: @"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"] forKey:@"dummyId"];

    [super awakeFromInsert];
}
```

So If anybody has an idea, it only happens in these NSOperations, so I guess that it is related to multithreading issues (maybe the context is being merged because of another thread ?). Anyway I don't know what's happening but I take any idea :)

Update :

I have one moc for each thread and basically they are created like this :

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)currentThreadContext
{
    static NSString * theKey = @"contextKey";
    NSManagedObjectContext * managedObjectContext = nil;

    NSThread * currentThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    if ((managedObjectContext = [[currentThread threadDictionary] objectForKey: theKey]) == nil)
    {
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator * coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
        if (coordinator != nil)
        {
            managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType: NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
            [managedObjectContext setStalenessInterval: 0];
            [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                         name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object: managedObjectContext];


            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(willSaveNotification:)
                                                         name: NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification object: managedObjectContext];

            // When the thread is deallocated we need to remove the observer for the current thread managed object context.

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(threadWillExit:)
                                                         name: NSThreadWillExitNotification object: currentThread];

            [[currentThread threadDictionary] setObject: managedObjectContext forKey: theKey];
        }
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

I use them like this [[CoreDataStack currentThreadContext] ...]

Comment: you need to show relevant code, like for example how you setup the contexts in your operations and relationships.

Comment: As `dummyId` is transformable have you set a transformer on it? You're setting it with the primitive setter.

Comment: Rich: Yes I'm setting a transformer on it, and some instances of this kind of entity have their dummyId attributes correctly set with the default value in awakeFromInsert. Only specific instances have their applicationId incorrectly set.

Comment: @Volker: I updated the code for the MOC creation, do you need more things?

Comment: i took a quick look, are you sure you get a new context for each NSOperation? Also I wouldn't update my thread contexts on save in other contexts... this may cause havoc.

Comment: @Volker: "havoc" ? what do you mean by "I wouldn't update my thread contexts on save in other contexts..." ? the only update is the "mergeChanges" that merge the contexts as I saw in all the core data examples.